# get selected lines from browse

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm trying to use a browse in Progress-4gl that will run a control-key to display the number of selected lines within the browse, as well as a total quantity from a temp table for all the lines selected.  I have been able to get the total number of lines easily, but when trying to get a total quantity from the temp-table I created, it just has the last selected row value.  How do I run a for each from the selected rows?
Here's some code I have for the browse:

```
on CTRL-L of browse-1 in frame a do:
   assign buf-cnt = 0.
   /***  FOR EACH BROWSE RECORD SELECTED **/
       assign jqty = jqty + int(tt.tt-qty).
   assign jlines = browse-1:num-selected-rows.
  display
       jlineslabel "Selected Number Of Lines"
       jqtylabel "Quantity Of All Lines"
       with frame fselect down row 5 centered overlay.
  pause.
end. /* on CTRL-L */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly you probably want the num-results attribute of the query handle that is associated with the browse -- which would be browse-1:query.  So:

```
jqty = browse-1:query:num-results.
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a little more specific. In the browse, I need to accumulate the total quantity (from the temp table column)for the items selected from the browse, not just the total number of columns. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks...I figured it out, and I also implemented your answer for more functionality.  I had to add:

     do x = 1 to browse-1:num-selected-rows:
       stat = browse-1:fetch-selected-row(x).
       /** FOR EACH STATEMENT **/
     end. /* do */
Thanks for your help @Tom Bascom

Answer (score 1):

for anyone wondering...

```
on CTRL-L of browse-1 in frame a do:
 assign buf-cnt = 0
        jqty = 0.
 do x = 1 to browse-1:num-selected-rows:
   stat = browse-1:fetch-selected-row(x).
   for each usrw_wkfl no-lock where
            usrw_wkfl.usrw_key1 = "862" and
            entry(1,usrw_wkfl.usrw_key2) = tt.tt-part and
            usrw_wkfl.usrw_key4 = tt.tt-dest and
            usrw_wkfl.usrw_key3 = tt.tt-duedate and
            usrw_wkfl.usrw_charfld[3] = tt.tt-qty:
      assign jqty = jqty + int(tt.tt-qty).
   end. /* for each usrw_wkfl */
 end. /* do x = 1 to browse-1 */
 assign jlines = browse-1:num-selected-rows
        jtotal = browse-1:query:num-results.
 display
      jlines         column-label "Selected Number!Of Lines"
      jtotal         column-label "Total Number!Of Lines"
      jqty           column-label "Quantity Of!All Lines"
      with frame fselect down row 5 centered overlay.
 pause.
```

end. /* on CTRL-L */